# How does one implement a container which exposes multiple ranges?

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

I have a container which (among other things) exposes a string buffer, and the upper case version of that string buffer. (Well, it isn't just upper case, but it is similar in concept) I want to allow a caller to do something similar to:

```
container c("Example");
auto const iter = c.begin() + 2;
std::printf("%c\n", iter->get_source()); // Prints a
std::printf("%c\n", iter->get_upper()); // Prints A
iter->set('x');

std::puts(c.get()); // Prints Exxmple
std::puts(c.get_upper()); // Prints EXXMPLE
```

The problem is, the "proxy" type with the member functions `get_source`, `get_upper`, etc. has no obvious place it can be stored, and an iterator is required to return a reference to something, not a value. (`vector<bool>` has a similar problem)

Alternately I could expose some kind of shell container or range, or expose completely separate iterator begin/end functions. Does anyone have experience doing something like this and know what works well?

Comment: The requirement that `operator*` returns `T&` is for forward iterators  (C++11 24.2.5 Forward Iterators [forward.iterators] para 1). For an input or output iterator, it does not apply.

Comment: @Casey: In this case exposing input and/or output iterators are not sufficient -- I'd like to support random access.

Comment: Looks like a job for _range views_

Comment: In my experience, most read-only algorithms work fine on iterator-like objects that do not return references.  Obviously, sort would not work.  The proxy type idiom is very convenient.

Answer (score 1):

My personal approach to this sort of things is to use *property maps*: I [envision a system](https://github.com/dietmarkuehl/kuhllib/wiki/STL-2.0) of algorithms which can [optionally] take a property map (or actually sometimes multiple property maps) for each range. The idea is that `*it` yields a *key* (e.g., the `T&` it currently do) which is then used with a property map which transforms the key into the actually accessed *value*. The transformation can, e.g., be the identity yielding the current behavior of the algorithms and a good default to be used when there is no property map. The example above would look something like this:

```
auto const cursor = c.begin();
std::printf("%c\n", c.map_source()(*cursor));
std::printf("%c\n", c.map_upper()(*cursor));
c.map_source()(*cursor, 'x');

std::copy(c.map_source(), c, std::ostreambuf_iterator<char>(std::cout));
std::copy(c.map_upper(), c, std::ostreambuf_iterator<char>(std::cout));
std::copy([](unsigned char c)->char{ return std::toupper(c); }, c,
          std::ostreambuf_iterator<char>(std::cout));
```

The code assumes that the property maps yielding the source and the capitalized characters are obtained using `c.map_source()` and `c.map_upper()`, respectively. The last variant using `std::copy()` uses a lambda function as a property map.

Sadly, I still haven't found the time to write up a coherent proposal to apply various improvements to the STL algorithms. ... nor do I have have an implementation putting it all together (I have a [somewhat clunky implementation](http://www.dietmar-kuehl.de/cxxrt/) which is about 10 years old and doesn't benefit from various C++11 features which make it a lot easier; also, this implementation only concentrates on property maps and doesn't use the interface I currently envision).

Comment: The problem is that this forces one to discard the huge body of work that is existing algorithms expecting iterator pairs or ranges. It might be an interesting concept to apply eventually by the standards committee, but I wouldn't call this an idiomatic solution as of C++11/14 and their standard libraries.

Comment: @BillyONeal: I certainly agree with the assessment that it doesn't play nicely with the current algorithms. I'm discussing the various changes involved (the above code uses _ranges_ and _property maps_ with the Ranges SG) where the ideas are generally well received.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not ripping on the ideas or anything like that; I'm just saying that doesn't answer the question *today* very well.